# Deploy .netcore to iis

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, iis-7, .net-core

I have a .net core app and runs fine on kestrel server. 
http://localhost:5000/mapapi/v1.0/branch

I have deployed the app to IIS using publish tool in visual studio 2017 and with in program.cs, I have this line of code

```
.UseIISIntegration()
```

when I run the app I get an error

An error occurred while starting the application.
Exception: Cannot read variable

It is not reading the variable from launchsettings.json. I also created a profile by the name "IIS"

```
"IIS": {
  "commandName": "iis",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "mapapi/v1.0/Branch",
  "environmentVariables": {
     "ConnectionString": "myhiddenconnectionstring",
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? what other places do I have to look and make sure the application reads the values appropriately. Anyone in the community who had experience .net core to IIS, please share you knowledge with the community. We would appreciate it.

Comment: launchSettings.json is only used by VS. If you want to use connection string based on environment then use `appsettings.{env}.json` and `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable.

Comment: Can you also post the content of your web.config file?